# Removing the big grey highlight behind the 'inlay-typehints' in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

While I was writing code in rust I noticed something that the inlay-typehint in vscode has a big grey highlight behind it. [The image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k72O.png)

I tried modifiying the hover box, messing around with the settings.json, but nothing seems to work. I also tried to grab information from google and youtube but they werent the same problem as I was facing, I am pretty sure I searched pretty deep.

Comment: you can change it using `editorInlayHint.background` and `editorInlayHint.foreground`

Comment: It shows 'Unknown Configuration Setting'.

Comment: I believe it has to be in a `workbench.colorCustomizations`. Sorry I didnt make that clear

Comment: File>Preferences>Settings, search for color customizations, click "Edit in settings.json"